# Change image in imageview on click on a listview

Tags: android, listview, imageview

I want to click on my listview (Rainbow Dash) and the image drawable/rainbowdash to be in the imageview instead of drawable/default.
I want to use the onclick method. If there is any suggestion to improve what i already have It'd be awesome. Thanks

This is my main activity.

```
package test.imagenes;
import java.util.ArrayList;

import android.net.ParseException;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.*;
import android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemClickListener;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.res.TypedArray;

public class SecondActivity extends Activity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.maindos);

    String[] ponies = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.ponies);
    final ListView listview = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.lista);
    final ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
    for (int i = 0; i < ponies.length; ++i) {
          list.add(ponies[i]);
        }


    ArrayAdapter<String> arrayAdapter =      
            new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, list);
    listview.setAdapter(arrayAdapter);
    listview.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener()
    {

        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View v, int position,
                long arg3) {
            String selectedPony=list.get(position);
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Pony Selected : "+selectedPony,   Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            TypedArray imgs= getResources().obtainTypedArray(R.array.poniesimg);
            ImageView image=(ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
            image.setImageResource(imgs.getResourceId(position,-1));
            imgs.recycle();

        }

    });

}
```

}

This is my list_data.xml

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <resources>
        <string-array name="ponies">
            <item>Rainbow Dash</item>
            <item>Apple Jack</item>
            <item>Rarity</item>
            <item>Pinkie Pie</item>
            <item>Twilight Sparkle</item>
            <item>Fluttershy</item>
        </string-array>
        <string-array name="poniesimg">
            <item>@drawable/rainbowdash</item>
            <item>@drawable/applejack</item>
            <item>@drawable/rarity</item>
            <item>@drawable/pinkiepie</item>
            <item>@drawable/twilightsparkle</item>
            <item>@drawable/fluttershy</item>
        </string-array>
    </resources>
```

This is my layout

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
 >

<ListView
    android:id="@+id/lista"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_below="@+id/imageView1" >

</ListView>

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="200dip"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

And what the log says is:
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{test.imagenes/test.imagenes.SecondActivity}: java.lang.ClassCastException: android.widget.ImageView cannot be cast to android.widget.ListView

Comment: At the moment I click in the names the app stops working

Comment: yes it is, and there is the layout and, not pretty sure what to look for, the log

Comment: sorry, I really don't know what to paste as log, all I see is:
Fatal exception:main
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError

Comment: Oh. Issue could be with the `drawable` your using. try changing to different image. For testing purpose first check with some icons to make sure issue with the image.

Comment: I don't think so, they are .png and less than 1600x1600
I also tried to set the image outside the listener

Comment: `1600x1600` png are sure a high resolution images. Try changing with some icons first. I believe there is some limitations on the images set in `ImageView`

Comment: crap... looks like that was the problem, let me recheck

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Issue should be with the `Drawables` your using. Try to change the `images`. For testing purpose check with some `low resolution images` .

Also, check this http://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/index.html

Also , try to recycle the `ImageView` before setting a new `drawable` when item selected in `ListView`

```
  ImageView image=(ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
  ((BitmapDrawable) image.getDrawable()).getBitmap().recycle();
  image.setImageResource(imgs.getResourceId(position,-1));
```

Comment: The problem was the images resolution.
Haven't tried that code, but I guess that cleans more the bitmap than just   `imgs.recycle`

Comment: Did you try recycle `ImageView`. If you still see the problem . You can also try to scale the image

Comment: No, `imgs.recycle` is your `TypedArray`